# ssh access by public key failed "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: ssh, server, ubuntu-14.04, public-key

I wanted to set up crontab to fetch resources from remote server to local server.

Steps used as below

In local server
 1. ssh-keygen with no passphrase
 2. copied the pubic key over to the server using SCP

In the remote server

1. cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
2. edited .ssh config file sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config as below
3. RSAAuthentication yes
4. PubkeyAuthentication yes
5. ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
6. PasswordAuthentication no
7. UsePam no
8. reload ssh by sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload
9. sudo chmod 700 .ssh
10. cd .ssh
11. sudo chmod 600 authorized_keys

After all this configuration, neither I am able to access remote server by public key or normal login credential into remote server.

If I tried to login through PuTTy asked for my login after has been entered. Its says "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods availble (server send: publickey)"

If I tried to login through SSH from local server ssh sana@127.168.1.1 it says "Permission denied (publickey)"

Server Details:
Ubuntu 14.04
I set up public key with another user not with root user.

Thanks in advance for all the support.

Comment: @fedorqui can you help me with this?

Comment: Check the logs on the remote ssh server for messages from sshd. The messages will most likely be in one of the files in the /var/log directory.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
chmod 444 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

the file should be only accessible to read and it should be accessible to read by your user.
And make sure that authorized_keys file is in the sana user home directory